# Callouts using the @future annotation or Queueable

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest

I have a contact trigger and I need to make a callout (GET) from trigger whenever the email of a contact is modified. I know I can do this from the @future in trigger, but online I see many examples using the queueable interface.

I am thinking of invoking this from the Process Builder using the @invocablemethod decorator, but last time I did with the queuable class I kept receiving the following error:

```
An Apex error occurred: System.LimitException: Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2
```

Did I receive this error because I was firing my class from Process builder? Is it best to not use process builder to invoke call outs? I am also not really sure what this limit exception REALLY means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference between the two techniques is that with future methods, you can't make any future calls, but with Queueable, you're allowed one more Queueable call. Regardless, you can't call more than one Queueable per asynchronous call.

If you choose to call an InvocableMethod, you must remember to check if you're in asynchronous code or not:

```
if(!System.isBatchable() && !System.isQueueable() && !System.isSchedulable() && !System.isFuture()) {
  doAsynchronousCall();
} else {
  doSynchronousCall(); // Or do nothing.
}
```

If you're not in asynchronous code, you can handle up to 50 of either future or Queueable calls in that transaction.

I can't tell exactly why you'd have gotten a "too many queueable calls: 2", except to say that obviously a second call was made while you were already asynchronous. It's most likely that you need to check for this recursion and avoid the extra callout.

Comment: How can I check for this recursion?

Comment: public class ZeroBounce {
    
    public static boolean isFutureCalled=false; ////Boolean variable to control 
if(isFutureCalled == false && !System.isBatchable() && !System.isQueueable() && !System.isSchedulable() && !!System.isFuture()){};
}

I am ussing the above to avoid the recursion. Does this look correct?

Comment: @MatthewMetros No, the static variable would be reset each time, so actually pointless, but simply checking if you're already asynchronous should suffice. You're right that I forgot about the other system method, though, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: looks like you wrote "isQueueable" twice. Just wanted to get your eyes on that

Comment: if(!System.isBatch() && !System.isQueueable() && !System.isScheduled() && !System.isFuture())

Comment: @MatthewMetros Thanks! That's what I meant to say. 

Comment: I tend to wrap this in a class/method that can support dependency injection so testmethods can exercise the paths

Answer (score 1):

There are certain limits to take into consideration when using queueables (like with pretty much everything in a multitenant environment as the Salesforce platform).

For queueables, you can schedule up to 50 queueable jobs in a single transaction, however once inside a Queueable context you can only schedule / chain a single (1) queueable job, in your case it seems you may be launching more than one inside an queueable context (will need more info on your implementation to point exactly where but seems to be the case)